# How to download a file from my flask website hosted on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, flask, google-cloud-platform

My flask website uses few excel files for indexing and searching details.
I've uploaded the excel files and python(flask) code on Google Cloud Platform.
The website works seamlessly, as intended and I have the website URL hosted on a domain as well.
Now, How do I download those excel files that I've uploaded before?
A python code to download them would be better.

File Directory

```
app.py
file1.xlsx
file2.xlsx
templates
    index.html
```

Comment: How do you want to download them? Via the website or an OS tool such as SSH/SCP?

Comment: 1) Which Google Cloud Platform product? 2) How were the files uploaded 3) Where are they uploaded to (cloud storage, saved as blobs, etc)? 4) How do you expect your users to download the files - by clicking on something or what? 5) Finally, you need to add code showing what you've done & where you're stuck.

Comment: Do you have latency concern? Or big size file?

Comment: I want to download them via the website.

1)App Engine
2)The files were uploaded using the CLI command - gcloud app deploy
3)Its not stored as a blob. I don't know where these files are stored.
4) It would be good if user could download the files with a button, however, my original idea was to automatically download the file when changes were made to it.

Its a relatively moderate file, with 10 sheets and approx 2000 rows